# Symfony2/JmsDIExtraBundle Injecting repository into service using annotations

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, annotations

In my project I’m using annotations with JMSDIExtraBundle. 
My question is: how I can tell my app that repository should be service so, I can inject it in another service using annotations.
**Only way I know is using XML file to define repository as service.** But it’s a very slow process(comparing it to simple @DI\Service which I prefer over defining it in yml or xml files).

I found an alternative solution to XML but I think it's bad idea:

```
   ####CustomService.php####
   /**
     * @param EntityManager $em
     *
     * @DI\InjectParams({
     *     "em" = @DI\Inject("doctrine.orm.entity_manager")
     * })
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }
```

And somewhere in service:

```
$entityRepository = $this->em->getRepository(AcmeBundle:Entity);
```

Any ideas how I can speed up coding process when I need to use repository?

Comment: I found only [this](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSDiExtraBundle/pull/115) but you must add the relative annotation in the custom repo. So nothing of so fast you are looking for...

Comment: Great! That's what I needed. But they said that injecting repositories is bad practice. I need to read about EntityManagers now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: yes, is not a great approach to couple and put business logic inside an Entity repository, sometime is the only thing you can do but if you can is better incapsulate the business logic inside a service that use the repository.

Comment: If you agree, i can integrate my answer so you can mark as solved the question. ok?

Comment: Of course! You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your entity repository as a service and inject it into the service.

As Example, you can configure the repo as a service like:

In a standard Symfony Service definition Way:

```
   ####service.xml####
    <service id="acme.user.repository"
             class="Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository"
             factory-service="doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
             factory-method="getRepository">
        <argument>AcmeDemoBundle:User</argument>
    </service>
```

Or using the `factory to Service annotation` defined in the JMSDiExtraBundle (see [this](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSDiExtraBundle/pull/115)):

```
/**
 * @Service("acme.user.repository", factoryService = "doctrine", factoryMethod="getRepository", factoryMethodArguments={
 * "persistentObjectName" = "Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\User"
 * } )
*/
```

And Inject and use it as:

```
   ####CustomService.php####
   /**
     * @param Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $repo
     *
     * @DI\InjectParams({
     *     "repo" = @DI\Inject("acme.user.repository")
     * })
     */
    public function __construct(EntityRepository $repo) {
        $this->repo = $repo;
    }
```

Is not a great speedup, but permit to only inject what you need

Hope this help

Comment: As i wrote, i know XML solution. But I search faster one.
So, there is no other option than using XML file?

Comment: You can of course use yml but what sort of "faster" are you looking for?  Quicker development?  Or faster execution?

Comment: I think @Warzyw is looking for something that speedup in terms of LOC

Comment: I agree but wanted to make sure.  I myself think that updating yaml files is faster then updating annotations but that's a personal opinion.  If he wants faster program execution then he needs to understand that the configuration is cached and thus they all run at the same speed.

Comment: Hi @Cerad I agree with your opinion, in terms of readability and performance too. The `jms/di-extra-bundle` use both annotation and AOP that is not really faster

Comment: Maybe not in terms of LOC, but in writing-time context. While using external files(xml for example) you have to open this file, write down the class name, and xml tags. So you are losing focus on programming and start brainless creating of config. While using annotations i stay in same file, just write one additional line of annotation. So I don't have to search for proper config file, copy existing entry and modify it to new repository.  
Someone wrote words of wisdom - Programmers are lazy guys.

Comment: factoryService and factoryMethod annotations were never merged into master, unfortunately.