# JMSDIExtraBundle declare repository as a service

Tags: php, symfony

I wanted to use solution which was described in this answer but it doesn't work. 
[Symfony2/JmsDIExtraBundle Injecting repository into service using annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28539070/symfony2-jmsdiextrabundle-injecting-repository-into-service-using-annotations)

I am using symfony 3 and my use case you can find below:

```
namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation as DI;
use UserBundle\Repository\UserRepository as BaseUserRepository;

    /**
     * @DI\Service("user_repository", factoryService = "doctrine", factoryMethod="getRepository", factoryMethodArguments={
     * "persistentObjectName" = "AppBundle\Model\User"
     * } )
     */
    class UserRepository extends BaseUserRepository
    {

    }
```

Base class:

```
namespace UserBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentRepository;
use UserBundle\Model\User;

abstract class UserRepository extends DocumentRepository
{
    public function save(User $user)
    {
        $dm = $this->getDocumentManager();
        $dm->persist($user);
        $dm->flush($user);
    }
}
```

And the command where I want to use UserRepository

```
class CreateAdminCommand extends BaseCreateAdminCommand
{    

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $this->userRepository = $this->getContainer()->get('user_repository');
    }
}
```

Next, when I want to execute my command I am getting this error:

> [Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]   [Creation Error]
>   The annotation @DI\Service declared on class
>   AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository does not have a property named
>   "factoryService".   Available properties: id, parent, public, scope,
>   shared, deprecated, decorates, decoration_inner_name, abstract,
>   environments

I agree with this error because I cannot find such property in Service annotation. So in my opinion it shouldn't work but it was described on another question and github as correct solution. I don't understand something here, could you help me Guys?

Comment: Why is the UserRepository abstract? I guess abstract classes cannot be autowired. Sec... maybe it's not obvious, which UserRepository do you autowire, since there is only "UserRepository". I recommend using Abstract prefix or some other unique-naming. Why not use more simple constructor injection?

Comment: Why UserRepository is abstract, why not? It is simple inheritance I think it does not matter in this case because I didn't define abstract class as a service. And  what do you mean 'Why not use more simple constructor injection?' You asking about CreateAdminCommand class?

Comment: Yes, I ask about "CreateAdminCommand". I think there is no magic required to do so. Since Autowiring added in Symfony 2.8+ JmsDIExtraBundle has no real added value here.

Comment: Hmm.. I did on thing wrong with CreateAdminCommand, I cannot inject repository like this, first it had to declare command as a service od extend ContainerAwareCommand. I will updated my code. ps. everything works fine with yml.

Comment: I'm glad it works fine.
CreateAdminCommand is Console Command (register as service is convention) or CQSR Command (not ok, should be in CommandHandler)?

Comment: It is console command it extends symfony ContainerAwareCommand

Comment: I see. No need to.